# Cannot use having clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to complete this question, but I am having some trouble. I am receiving

> 'Column 'DOG.DOB' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

error. There is no Age column. Below is a [picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyoOL.png) and the desired output. I will also put my code down below

```
select
    Name AS 'Dog Name',
    DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB) AS 'Age'
from DOG
Having
    DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB) > avg(DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB))
ORDER BY AGE DESC
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It's relevant, and whenever you use the SQL tag you should also add a tag for the specific DBMS as well - if you hover your mouse over the SQL tag and read the text that is displayed, it tells you that also. Please edit and add that tag so that we can try to help.

Comment: There is an `Age` column because you create it by aliasing your `DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB)` with it.

Comment: Your assignment asks you to use a subquery - if you follow that, you you won't be `HAVING` (pun intended) the issue you are experiencing with your current attempt. Hint: The subquery serves to select the AVG age and it's result will be used for the WHERE condition of your outer query.